# Get the selected language when using $translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I've setup the $translate project from [here](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/00_installation) in my angularjs app.

In my app.config() I've set the default language to the $translateProvider but how to get the selected language in the langCtrl? 
Does $translate have a get function for this?

```
angular.module('app').config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix: 'locale-',
      suffix: '.json'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
}]);

angular.module('app').controller('langCtrl', ['$scope', '$translate',
    function ($scope, $translate) {

        $scope.lang = ''; //here I need to set the selected language

        $scope.setLanguage = function (langKey) {
            $translate.use(langKey);
        };
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official doc](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate) we can tell that with `$translate.use()` we can determine the current used language.

> (...)
>
> use([key])
>
> If no or a falsy key is given it returns the currently used language
>   key. The returned string will be undefined if setting up $translate
>   hasn't finished.

Comment: Thanks! Looked everywhere on their site but missed this.

Comment: You're welcome :) It was hard to fully comprehend the API for me too the first time I saw the docs